# Insert new array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to insert new array into my multidimensial array. I divided my array by date and now I should insert into date new array. I wrote php however it insert outside of the date.

### Array

```
Array
(
[2016-05-31 00:00:00] => Array
    (
        [Основной долг] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 0
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => CLICK
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1971022
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 564550
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 122714
                    )

            )

        [Депозит] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1175942
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1316410
                    )

            )

        [] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 100
                        [oper_type] => 
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => 
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 843795
                    )

            )

    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [click_count] => test
        [bill_count] => test
        [terminal_count] => test
        [time_pay] => 2016-05-01
        [count_all] => test
        [name_oper] => Итого
    )

)
```

### PHP

```
foreach ($data["reports"][1] as $value) {
      $bydate[$value['time_pay']][$value['name_oper']][] = $value;
    }

    $calculation =  array (
      'click_count' => 'test',
      'bill_count' => 'test',
      'terminal_count' => 'test',
      'time_pay' => '2016-05-01',
      'count_all' => 'test',
      'name_oper' => 'Итого'
    );

    $bydate[] = $calculation;
```

### What I want to do

```
Array
(
[2016-05-31 00:00:00] => Array
    (
        [Основной долг] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 0
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => CLICK
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1971022
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 564550
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 122714
                    )

            )

        [Депозит] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1175942
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1316410
                    )

            )

        [] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 100
                        [oper_type] => 
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => 
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 843795
                    )

            )

        [Итого] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [click_count] => test
                        [bill_count] => test
                        [terminal_count] => test
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31
                        [count_all] => test
                        [name_oper] => Итого
                    )

            )

    )

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
foreach ($data["reports"][1] as $value) {
  $bydate[$value['time_pay']][$value['name_oper']][] = $value;
}

$calculation =  array (
  'click_count' => 'test',
  'bill_count' => 'test',
  'terminal_count' => 'test',
  'time_pay' => '2016-05-01',
  'count_all' => 'test',
  'name_oper' => 'Итого'
);

$bydate[$value['time_pay']]['Итого'][0] = $calculation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have to provide the Index value to your array. In the example you are using the Date as first index and name_oper as second index. Because **your array is static** you can use static values as index values.

`$bydate[$value['time_pay']]['Итого'][] = $calculation;`

but if your array is generated on the run time then you have to use variable for your index values.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try php built in `array_push` function. specify the index of that value to array_push

```
array_push($arr['index'], $newArr);
```